# Find out status of last build in shell script

Tags: jenkins

I have a job with Shell script which runs every after 30 mins, download and accept changes from source control. Now I want to proceed in my shell script if and only if;

- There are new changes in my workspace OR
- There are NO new changes but my last run for the same job was marked as unstable.

I have looked at the Jenkins wiki but from the obvious environment variable it is not possible to find out 'if my last run' was Stable or Unstable without writing code within my build either via using Jenkins XML API or some python script...Is there any easy way to find this information?

Comment: What source control are you using?

Comment: Its Rational Team Concert. We have its plugin but recently we have updated the Source Control server and the Jenkins plugin now fails to Accept any change...Plugin use to do this for us before...but now we have to perform this temporarily until plugin is fixed!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use a URL API, unless you want to complicate it even further with `jenkins-cli`

`/api/json` end-point is the easiest to use in shell/bash as it provides all information in a single line. We can then grep it for the data we need, strip out the leading identifier, and get the result.

You have access to the current build number as `BUILD_NUMBER` and can calculate the previous one. You also have access to convenient `JOB_URL`.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Calculate previous build number
prevBuild=$(($BUILD_NUMBER - 1))

# Get previous run status, returns like: result":"UNSTABLE
prevStatus=`curl -silent http://${JOB_URL}/${prevBuild}/api/json | grep -iEo 'result":"\w*'`

# Strip out leading identifier, i.e: result":"
prevStatus=${prevStatus/result\"\:\"/}

if [[ "$prevStatus" == "UNSTABLE" ]]; then
    do_whatever
fi
```

Comment: I think provided the available api this is the best and easiest way to perform it in shell. Thanks.

Comment: I would add: Do yourself a favor and learn a tool like jq (http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) so you do not have to parse json with line-oriented unix tools.

Answer (score 4):

You can make curl call directly to http://${JOB_URL}/lastBuild/api/json

No need to get prev build number.